# Sending data from Configuration Activity to AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I've got a widget and configuration Activity for this widget. 
The question is how to send data from configuration Activity to widget? I've tried using intents with putExtra(), but how to catch intent in the widget? Are there any patterns?

This is what I have for now:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
bd = new DateTime(  
datePick.getYear(), 
datePick.getMonth()+1, 
datePick.getDayOfMonth(),  
timePick.getCurrentHour(),  
timePick.getCurrentMinute());

//this is first variant             
Intent sendDateIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
sendDateIntent.putExtra("birthDate", bd.getMillis());

//this is second variant
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra("birthDate", bd.getMillis());
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the link to the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

`Additionally, you can implement an App Widget configuration Activity. This is an optional Activity that launches when the user adds your App Widget and allows him or her to modify App Widget settings at create-time.

The following sections describe how to setup each of these components.`

Everything you need is detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration).  (note click on this link for a step by step procedure to do exactly what you want.  Do I need to copy the docs to this website to get accepted?

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for - the OP is looking for a way to pass the date selected in the activity to the widget somehow.

Comment: @jrharshath  I'm not seeing that.  I think he is trying to send it directly, but what would be the point.  The config activity obscures the Widget.  The OP is trying to get the data from the config activity to the widget which is what an App Widget configuration Activity is designed to do.

Comment: I am curious?  has anyone actually followed the link `here` that takes you to the doc section entitled "Updating the App Widget from the configuration Activity" which clearly is what the op is asking for?